# Stretch div to max-height

Tags: css, html

How to make second `div` (`.rightcolumnSmal`) to stretch full down?

**Code**:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px dashed orange;
}
.leftcolumnBig {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1px 0 0;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px dashed orange;
}
.rightcolumnSmal {
  width: 17%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #FCFAAC;
  float: right;
  border: 1px dashed orange;
  padding: 0 0 0 1px;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="leftcolumnBig">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumnSmal">
    Try to fill max down to the end
  </div>

</div>
```

Also a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sickworm/fba2mbkt/).

---

To look something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sickworm/fba2mbkt/1/):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px dashed orange;
}
.leftcolumnBig {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1px 0 0;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
.rightcolumnSmal {
  width: 17%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #FCFAAC;
  float: right;
  border: 1px dashed orange;
  padding: 0 0 0 1px;
  margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="leftcolumnBig">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumnSmal">
    Try to fill max down to the end
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BrettEast/bzca8f83/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the floats and set the display to table-cell (`display:table-cell;`) for the `leftcolumnBig` and `rightcolumnSmal` divs:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fba2mbkt/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your definition of height and your definition of max. If you want an element to extend to 100% of the view height, you can use height: 100%, or as I prefer, height: 100vh.

Here is a jsfiddle that Brett East posted in your commments.

If, however, you want the page to have enough content in a separate element on the screen where the user will scroll down, and the div will reach as far down as the content is, you need to have the one element be aware of the other element. Here is some javascript I used to accomplish that in a past project.

```
var height = $('.element-with-content').height();
$('.element-to-have-matching-height').css({ 'height': height });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.rightcolumnSmal {
     width: 17%;
     min-height: 100vh;
     display: block;
     background-color: #FCFAAC;
     float: right;
     border: 1px dashed orange;
     padding: 0 0 0 1px;
     margin:1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

Min height needs to be 100vh, not 100%. 100vh is the height of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a table to make them the same height: http://jsfiddle.net/fba2mbkt/6/

```
.mainwrapper{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

.leftcolumnBig {
     display: table-cell;
     width: 80%;
     border: 1px dashed orange;
}

.rightcolumnSmal {
     display: table-cell;
     width: 17%;
     background-color: #FCFAAC;
     border: 1px dashed blue;
     padding: 0 0 0 1px;
     margin:1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
```